# Can I bet on who I think will win the hand at a casino?

Tags: cash-game, etiquette, casino

Would I be allowed to say to my friend at the table "I bet 10 dollars that gentleman there wins this hand." Assuming that both of us are not currently in the hand.

Is this rude? Is this legal?

Comment: I think it's probably inappropriate for you to discuss this at the table where the people who are still in the hand can hear, since it may affect their decisions. Also it might reek of impropriety, since there may be some relationship (or the perception of a possible relationship) between one of the side bettors and the actual players that may affect the way the hand is played.

Comment: @ChrisFarmer Your comment is probably enough to be warranted as an answer. It may be short but it seems appropriate enough to convert it.

Comment: I thought it would be illegal because it is "placing a bet on a game of chance."

Comment: @ChrisFarmer You have the start of a good answer there. Would you mind making it an answer ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like Chris's comment as the answer. I would say no, you cannot. It is tacky and rude. It is not a bet within the scope of the casino's license, so technically it is an illegal bet. To make the bet you would have to discuss the hand in progress in such a way as to violate the rule about discussing the hand in progress.

Comment: I agree. Not much good would come of trying this. At best, you'd have at least one player at the table thinking you're a jerk for rooting against him.

Comment: Those rude jerks at Poker After Dark... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It's poor sportsmanship, and almost certainly against casino rules.

To make that remark, you would probably have seen someone's hand, or if a skilled poker player, observed someone's body language or "tell." In any event, by making a bet, you are commenting on a game in progress. This is forbidden to both players and spectators.